# The best way to work with SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, production-environment

I'm trying to implement SVN in my organization. We have 2 servers: production and development.
Some programmers have their own copy of the system.

How we work at this moment:
Development server is under trunk. Some programmers work directly on it. If programmer has his own copy - he has private branche in svn.

The main problem is with production server. In our system we have no release versions, so - no tags in svn. I've created separate branche for production - master. If we need to transfer some commits from develop to production - we merge trunk and master branch.

Maybe there are other ways to transfer and control changes to production server?
Or use a different version control system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "programmers have their own copy"...if you are using SVN, they all must have a local copy in order to work.

Anyway, I'll recommend having a read at the [Version Control with Subversion (the SVNBook)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html), more specifically at the [basic working cycle](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html) and check how [tags](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.htmlAe) are used. It is definitely easier to use than merging your branches against the trunk each time you want to make a 'release', although sometimes you'll have to do this anyway.

You can also consider using other SCM, such as [Git](http://git-scm.com/documentation), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/guide/) or [Bazaar](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.5/en/user-guide/index.html). I really like Git, but Bazaar probably is one of the best SCM ever designed: easy to use and as good as Git. Git is really nice but can take some time to master, specially if you come from SVN.

Switching from one SCM to another is no easy task, specially if you have already quite a lot of repositories, so if you plan to do so, do it first with a small one, test it, try to keep version history from SVN (there are [tools](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) for these if destination is Git) and then go for the big one.

Comment: I mean that not all programmers have local copy, some of them work directly on development server. I know about tags, but i don't understand following: if i've many commints during the day - i should do the same amount of tags?

Comment: Adding tags is completely based on your release strategy. Depending on how are you versioning your software this can imply a new release each time a bug is fixed, or a new feature is added or only when a major set of features than imply new architectural decisions have been made. For instance, if you use a typical 3 digit version scheme X.X.X, where each can be represented as: Major Feature. Minor Feature. Bug fixing, I would make a new release for each of those.

Comment: Ok. How to resolve following situation: we have 1 file. 2 programmers has commited some changes to trunk (revisions 182 and 183 for example). We need to transfer to production only 183 revision, but if i make tag with 183 revision - it will contain 182 revision too.

Comment: Well, they should have never commited to the trunk. I mean, each of them should have their own branch, and then merged to the trunk and then make a new release. In your case, if one of them merged first, and then the other (the one that should be tagged) merged afterwards, I would roll back to revision 181 and then merge the latest. Not efficient, but it could work. Also, if you want them to commit to the trunk directly, at lest tell them to lock the files that are being modified by many developers...at least that enforces the update-lock-modify-unlock-commit cycle.